# Get the text from a div with a certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big div containing many divs inside, I need to get the text from those inner divs but at certain condition, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < g; i++)
        {
            var h = $('#infor > div').["dataid = i"].text();
            alert(h);
        }
```

(infor) is the id for the big div and (dataid) is the attribute of the inner divs

Comment: Show html code or create jsfiddle

Comment: Could you provide [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if possible? And what's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
 var h = $('#infor > div[dataid = '+ i +']').text();
```